# Array with specific indices

Tags: arrays, memory-management, fortran, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to have an array with custom allocatable indices in Fortran?

For example

> integer a(3:7)

will create following elements: a(3), a(4), a(5), a(6), and a(7).

Is there any way to create, say, only a(3), a(5), and a(7) to save memory, as other elements will never be used?

If that is possible for static case, can we have similar thing for dynamic case?

**Edit**:

say I have a complicated expression with various a(i,j,k). Now depending on i,j,k, a(i,j,k) can be assigned some external function "F" with different arguments. Here i,j,k can non-uniformly go up to 1000, i.e, say, 'i' takes values 12,16,34,...,999 etc only.But in my code if I declare "integer a(1000,1000,1000)" that will be a waste of memory.

> COMMON/I/i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6
>
> a(i1,i2,i3)=F(1)
>
> a(i3,i2,i4)=F(2)
>
> a(i1+i4,i5,i3)=F(3)
>
> function=a(i1,i2,i3) *(...) + a(i3,i2,i4) *(...) + ...

Now changing all the instances of a(i,j,k) in the expression by the external function would be a solution, but I don't want to modify the expression. That is why, I was wondering whether there is any alternative without wasting lot of memory.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.  But, depending on what you want to do, there may be alternative data structures that are better suited.  Or, just pretend that the array `b(1:3)` is the same as `a([3,5,7])`.

Comment: If you let us know *what* you're trying to do we may be able to propose some alternative solutions.

Comment: @francescalus, now there is an addendum to explain what I want to do.

Comment: No, there is nothing like that. You would have to invent some custom data structure. But even that would require changing the expression. I suggest you to re-think your program design.